# Don't understand cause of this IndentationError in my tic tac toe script

Tags: python

I am doing this according to a tutorial and the code is just the same as his, but he does not have an error like this. Can you please help me? Thank you.

```
def check_for_winner():
  #check rows
  row_winner = check_rows()

  #check columns
  column_winner = check_columns()

  #check diagonals
  diagonal_winner = check_diagonals()

  if row_winner:
    #there was a win

  elif column_winner:
    #there was a win
  elif diagonal_winner:
    #there was a win  


  return
```

ERROR: File "main.py", line 75     elif column_winner:  ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: A comment alone can't serve as a statement. The parser is seeing the `elif column_winner` line immediately after `if row_winner`, with no indented line between them.

Comment: You can use "pass" as a statement which does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There are no statements in the body of your `elif column_winner` and `elif diagonal_winner` conditionals. You can temporarily add `pass` or any dummy statement to get the code to compile.

```
if row_winner:
    #there was a win
    pass
elif column_winner:
    #there was a win
    pass
elif diagonal_winner:
    #there was a win  
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

You might have put unintentional tabs in between them. Try typing it once more. Keep in mind the spaces. Else delete the 2 lines above and below the line showing error and type them again.

Comment: while your suggestion is valid and might hold for some cases, I think in this specific case it is obvious what is the problem, as suggested in other answers and comments